# Word translator program based on string comparison - heap memory assertion fails

Tags: c, arrays, string, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

I made a program that reads from file `english_dictionary.txt` the 200 most frequently used words in the English language, and in `foreign_dictionary.txt` I put the translations of the respective words in a foreign language.

The content of the .txt files is placed in two `char *` type array of `200` elements.

Then the program reads from file `text_to_translate.txt`, that containing a text in English, and would replace the strings(words) in English with foreign ones if it finds a match (this happens inside the `compute_text` function). But it does not work, i've the failure of assertion about heap memory, so i suppose i've wrong something with malloc or something like that, but i can't understand where i wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void foreign_dictionary(char **foreign, FILE *fp){

    char *buffer = malloc(30 * sizeof(char));
    char *tok;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 200; ++i){
        fgets(buffer, 29, fp);
        tok = strtok(buffer, "\n");
        foreign[i] = malloc(strlen(tok) + 1);
        strcpy(foreign[i], tok);
    }

    free(tok);
    free(buffer);
}

void dictionary(char **english, FILE *fp){

    int i;
    char *tok;

    char *buffer = malloc(30 * sizeof(char));

    for (i = 0; i < 200; ++i){
        fgets(buffer, 29, fp);
        tok = strtok(buffer, " \n");
        english[i] = malloc(strlen(tok) + 1);
        strcpy(english[i], tok);
    }
    free(buffer);
    free(tok);
}

void compute_text(char **text,FILE *fp){

    char *buffer;
    int i, j, flag = 0, words_number = 0, cnt_letters_word = 0;

    buffer = malloc(100 * sizeof(char));

    while (fgets(buffer, 100, fp) != NULL){
        for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i){
            if (buffer[i] == ' ' || buffer[i] == '\0'){
                text[words_number] = malloc((cnt_letters_word + 1)* sizeof(char));
                for (j = 0; j < cnt_letters_word; ++j){
                    if (isupper(buffer[flag + j]))
                        text[words_number][j] = tolower(buffer[flag + j]);
                    else
                        text[words_number][j] = buffer[flag + j];
                }
                text[words_number][cnt_letters_word] = '\0';
                flag = i + 1;
                cnt_letters_word = 0;
                ++words_number;
            }
            else if (buffer[i] == '\n' || buffer[i] == ',' || buffer[i] == '.' || buffer[i] == ';' || buffer[i] == ':')
                ;
            else
                ++cnt_letters_word;
        }
        flag = 0;
        cnt_letters_word = 0;
    }
    free(buffer);
}

int main(void){

    char *foreign[200], *english[200], *text[50];

    FILE *fp = fopen("foreign_dictionary.txt", "r");
    foreign_dictionary(foreign, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("english_dictionary.txt", "r");
    dictionary(english, fp);
    fclose(fp);
    fp = fopen("text_to_translate.txt", "r");
    compute_text(text, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Next time look into [`valgrind`](http://valgrind.org/) for any problem possibly related to memory allocation.

Comment: @Jongware KILLER APP, thanks! There is something similar for windows too?

Comment: Sorry, I did not know it's for Mac/Linux only: "Windows is not under consideration because porting to it would require so many changes it would almost be a separate project" ([valgrind/platforms](http://valgrind.org/info/platforms.html)). But see [Is there a good Valgrind substitute for Windows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/413477/is-there-a-good-valgrind-substitute-for-windows) for a list of suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your code, `tok` is not pointing to dynamically allocated memory. You need not (and can not) `free()` it. Remove

```
 free(tok);
```

from the code.

From the [man page of `free()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/free)

> The `free(ptr)` function frees the memory space pointed to by `ptr`, which must have been returned by a previous call to `malloc()`, `calloc()` or `realloc()`. Otherwise, or if `free(ptr)` has already been called before,  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
>    occurs.

That said, always check the return value of `fopen()` and `malloc()` (and possibly, all library functions) to ensure success before using the returned pointer.